# Row Mapper/Converter to convert list of object array to a json in spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, json, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

I have a `mysql` `stored procedure` which joins multiple tables and returns a table. I am invoking the `stored procedure` from my `Spring data` `repository` -

```
@Query(value = "CALL get_emp_details(:id);", nativeQuery = true)
     public List<Object[]> getEmpDetails(@Param("id") long id);
```

The above method return `List<Object[]>`.

```
[[1890372504,0,"emp.new4444@gmail.com","GB","FUND","GRP280150","GBP","090950a4-ea97-4dc0-b109-702000c47c16","Org-258","GRP280150",1],[1890372504,0,"emp.new4444@gmail.com","GB","FUND","GRP280150","GBP","89d7a44f-b9b7-4d06-b8c2-137d4e7b8e8a","Org-258",null,1]
```

I want to convert this list of object array for `Employee` `1890372504` to a json.
Any idea on how to achieve that? Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Please note procedure

> get_emp_details(:id)

select query should have "as" clause same as entity class(POJO) attributes i.e employee and replace

> List<Object[]> to List< Employee>

Comment: ```"No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.example.dto.Employee]"```

I am getting this error.